# Django, such table not found

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models

I have set up a Project with Django and defined in the models some tables, also the table "Artikel":

```
class Artikel(models.Model):
    anr = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    anzahl = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    bez = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    preis = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    info = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Anr: {}, Anzahl: {}'.format(self.anr, self.anzahl)
```

Then I have used makemigration and migrate to migrate the defined tables to the database (runserver also works without Errors) but when I open now the shell with the command:

```
python manage.py shell
```

When I use following commands to create a object and I save it:

```
from shop.models import *
a = Artikel(anr=1, anzahl=1, bez='test', preis=1.99, info='test')
a.save()
```

I get the following error by the method a.save()

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "E:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 796, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "E:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 824, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "E:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 889, in _save_table
    forced_update)
  File "E:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 939, in _do_update
    return filtered._update(values) > 0
  File "E:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 654, in _update
    return query.get_compiler(self.db).execute_sql(CURSOR)
  File "E:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1148, in execute_sql
    cursor = super(SQLUpdateCompiler, self).execute_sql(result_type)
  File "E:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 835, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "E:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "E:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "E:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "E:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "E:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "E:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 337, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: shop_artikel
```

Generated Migration data:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

initial = True

dependencies = [
]

operations = [
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Adresse',
        fields=[
            ('strasse', models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)),
            ('hnr', models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)),
            ('plz', models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
            ('ort', models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)),
        ],
        options={
            'verbose_name_plural': 'Adressen',
        },
    ),
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Artikel',
        fields=[
            ('anr', models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
            ('anzahl', models.CharField(max_length=5)),
            ('bez', models.CharField(max_length=255)),
            ('preis', models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=7)),
            ('info', models.CharField(max_length=255)),
        ],
    ),
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Bestellung',
        fields=[
            ('bestellnummer', models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
            ('datum', models.DateField()),
            ('status', models.CharField(max_length=20)),
        ],
    ),
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Feedback',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('bemerkung', models.CharField(max_length=255)),
            ('datum', models.DateField()),
        ],
    ),
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Kunde',
        fields=[
            ('knr', models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
            ('name', models.CharField(max_length=255)),
            ('email', models.CharField(max_length=255)),
            ('zuletzt_online', models.DateField(null=True)),
            ('adresse', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='shop.Adresse')),
        ],
    ),
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Land',
        fields=[
            ('name', models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
        ],
    ),
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Warenkorb',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('anzahl', models.CharField(max_length=3)),
        ],
    ),
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Bluray',
        fields=[
            ('artikel_ptr', models.OneToOneField(auto_created=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, parent_link=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, to='shop.Artikel')),
            ('regisseur', models.CharField(max_length=50)),
            ('jahr', models.DateField()),
            ('genre', models.CharField(max_length=50)),
        ],
        bases=('shop.artikel',),
    ),
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Buch',
        fields=[
            ('artikel_ptr', models.OneToOneField(auto_created=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, parent_link=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, to='shop.Artikel')),
            ('autor', models.CharField(max_length=50)),
            ('verlag', models.CharField(max_length=50)),
            ('isbn', models.CharField(max_length=13)),
        ],
        bases=('shop.artikel',),
    ),
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='SonstigerArtikel',
        fields=[
            ('artikel_ptr', models.OneToOneField(auto_created=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, parent_link=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, to='shop.Artikel')),
        ],
        bases=('shop.artikel',),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='warenkorb',
        name='artikel',
        field=models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='shop.Artikel'),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='warenkorb',
        name='bestellung',
        field=models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='shop.Bestellung'),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='feedback',
        name='artikel',
        field=models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='shop.Artikel'),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='feedback',
        name='kunde',
        field=models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='shop.Kunde'),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='bestellung',
        name='artikel',
        field=models.ManyToManyField(through='shop.Warenkorb', to='shop.Artikel'),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='bestellung',
        name='kunde',
        field=models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='shop.Kunde'),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='bestellung',
        name='lieferadr',
        field=models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='shop.Adresse'),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='adresse',
        name='land',
        field=models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.PROTECT, to='shop.Land'),
    ),
]
```

Comment: Could you include the generated migration file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete your migrations files and drop the database and recreate it. Then,

```
rm -r shop/migrations
rm -rf db.sqlite3

python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Check that you have added "shop" in `INSTALLED_APPS` in your settings.py

Then open the shell, try the same again.